# More than one e-mail address in the same domain

Tags: hyperref

Suppose we have 3 people whose e-mail addresses are

```
aa@gmail.com

bb@gmail.com

cc@gmail.com
```

When I try to group these three addresses like

```
{aa, bb, cc}@gmail.com
```

one problem happens. If I move the mouse near `cc`, there is one wrong message `"mailto: ccg@gmail.com"`. I guess the letter `g` is the original }.

So how can I simply forbiden these `"mailto"` message, for example, simply leave the addresses as a plain text ? Anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: With the `hyperref` package you can do `\nolinkurl{{aa, bb, cc}@gmail.com}`?

Comment: Welcome!  Could you please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 3):

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\emails}[2][@gmail.com]{%
    \def\@tempa{\@gobble}%
    \@for\qrr@email:=#2\do{%
        \edef\@tempb{\noexpand\href{mailto:\qrr@email #1}{\qrr@email}}%
        \edef\@tempa{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@tempa}{, }\unexpanded\expandafter{\@tempb}}}%
    \{\@tempa\}#1%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\{aa, bb, cc\}@gmail.com              \par
\texttt{\{aa, bb, cc\}@gmail.com}     \par
{\urlstyle{same}
  \nolinkurl{{aa, bb, cc}@gmail.com}} \par
\nolinkurl{{aa, bb, cc}@gmail.com}    \par

\emails{aa,bb,cc}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]